# change format of date from JSON to first 2 letters and year

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON, and I need to convert the date values eg. "December 2016" to "D16", not sure how I could do this, I guess with a Regex, any help would be appreciated.

```
[["November 2016","December 2016","January 2017","February 2017","March 2017"],["total",2,43,59,51,41
],["mammo",1,20,33,12,12],["face",1,20,16,30,27],["body",0,3,10,9,2],["photo",0,19,27,12,5],["scan",2
,24,32,39,36]]
```

Comment: Never work directly on the JSON itself. _Always_ decode it into the native language, then manipulate or read the properties you need. If it needs to be JSON again when you're don, re-encode it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dates = ["November 2016","December 2016","January 2017","February 2017","March 2017"];

dates = dates.map((date) => date[0] + date.split(' ')[1].slice(2, 4))

console.log(dates)
//["N16", "D16", "J17", "F17", "M17"]
```

You could use some library like moment if you need to do some other magic with the date though.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you could use a regular expression to match the required text and replace the elements of the first date array. Try this:

```js
var arr = [
  ["November 2016", "December 2016", "January 2017", "February 2017", "March 2017"],
  ["total", 2, 43, 59, 51, 41],
  ["mammo", 1, 20, 33, 12, 12],
  ["face", 1, 20, 16, 30, 27],
  ["body", 0, 3, 10, 9, 2],
  ["photo", 0, 19, 27, 12, 5],
  ["scan", 2, 24, 32, 39, 36]
];

arr[0] = arr[0].map(function(date) {
  return date.replace(/^(\w{1}).*(\d{2})$/gi, "$1$2");
})

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 ['November16'].map(word => word.substring(0,1).concat(word.slice(-2)))
```